# How to load a specific js file from local assets instead loading it from website for faster loading in android WebView?

Tags: android, android-webview

Here is my simple attempt to achieve that but the app crashed. I basically want to replace the remote js file with a file stored in assets folder. What I simply want is to load a large 'vendor.js' file from assets folder instead fetching it while loading the website so as to reduce the loading time.

```
package example.javatpoint.com.webview;  
  
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;  
import android.os.Bundle;  
import android.webkit.WebView;  
  
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {  
  
    @Override  
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  
        WebView mywebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);  

        /*Here is what I tried */
       mywebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest (final WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
                String url = request.getUrl().toString();
                if (url.contains("vendor.js")) {
                    return getCssWebResourceResponseFromAsset();
                } else {
                    return  super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, request);
                    //return shouldInterceptRequest(view, request.getUrl().toString());
                }
            }
            private WebResourceResponse getUtf8EncodedCssWebResourceResponse(InputStream data) {
                return new WebResourceResponse("text/javascript", "UTF-8", data);
            }

            /**
             * Return WebResourceResponsefrom an asset (e.g. "assets/vendor.js").
             */
            private WebResourceResponse getCssWebResourceResponseFromAsset() {
                try {
                    return getUtf8EncodedCssWebResourceResponse(getAssets().open("vendor.js"));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    return null;
                }
            }

            


        });
//Intercept request and alter accordingly
        mywebview.loadUrl("https://example.com");  
    }  
}
```

Comment: What is the problem with your current approach?

Comment: Application is crashing upon launch

Comment: Can you post the error log?

Answer (score 0):

There was some other issue behind the crash and the above approach works perfectly fine.